# cannot run software updater on 15.10

Tags: update-manager

I started my Ubuntu 15.10 and am unable to open the software updater app. I keep getting the following error

```
SystemError: E:Malformed line 55 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list (dist parse)
```

I tried purging the app and reinstalling, but still get the same error. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Do the following to recreate your `sources.list`. Open a terminal () and type:

```
sudo su
```

Then recreate your sources list by copy&paste the following block into the terminal and press return once.

```
cat > /etc/apt/sources.list << EOF
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu wily main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu wily main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu wily-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu wily-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu wily-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu wily-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu wily-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu wily-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu wily partner
deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu wily partner
EOF
```

After that simply type `exit` to return to your normal user mode. All should be performing normally then.

Comment: Thanks, that solved the problem.  I appreciate your help as I am a newbie to Linux.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu, if the question helped and solved your problem you can accept it by clicking the checkmark beside it.